# How do I implement tracking using Google Maps API?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, tracking

I am trying to make an app which tracks the path of the user. I wish to use the google maps API for this. I know there is a specific "tracking API" but that is deprecated now. I used the tutorial at http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android but that only shows me my location. It doesn't show how to track.

I tried to use the google developers support documents, but its simply too confusing. I am a beginner, so if someone could just guide me I'd appreciate it. Kindly assume I know JUST the basics.

Comment: You mention Android and tagged your question with the Google Maps Javascript API v3. What do you want to use?

Comment: You simply could save the received location in `onLocationChanged` in a list of locations and when the user stops tracking you evaluate the results and calculate the distance with from the coordinates.
Maybe you could provice us more information, what things you want to track (e.g. average speed, distance, pace, etc.)

Comment: Hey guys, So basically. There's a "start workout" option. I want the device to track location starting from then till the time the user clicks "stop workout". I want to know basic details like the path traveled-shown by the maps, and average speed, distance traveled, pace, calories consumed etc. Now, calories n all I'll figure out later. Right now just the basics.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I wish to use the google maps api.

Comment: That does **not** answer the question at all. What is "google maps api"? https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm so sorry, what I meant is this one:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro 
like how it is shown here:
http://i67.tinypic.com/2zyivxg.png